Programatically sync a TFS workspace for .Net 6+ or greater
The following code works fine for .Net 4.8 with Nuget Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient Version="16.205.1"
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

namespace TfsWorkspaceGet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create VSS credentials
            VssBasicCredential vssCred = new VssBasicCredential(
                "valid userid", 
                "valid PAT token");

            // connect to TFS
            var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://someorg.com/tfs/projects"));
            tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

            //connect to Azure DevOps using the basic credentials
            var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(tfsUrl), vssCred);

            var versionControlServer = tfsCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            // Create a workspace
            Workspace workspace = versionControlServer.CreateWorkspace("tmpTfsWorkspace");

            // Map the server path to the local path
            workspace.CreateMapping(new WorkingFolder(
                "$/SomProj/Mainline/DEV/SomeComponent", 
                @"D:\WS\SomProj\Mainline\DEV\SomeComponent"));

            // Get the latest version
            workspace.Get();
        }
    }
}

Am trying to get it upgraded to working with .Net 6+... unsuccessfully

Just upgrading the Nuget to consume .Net compatible Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient Version="19.225.1" shows multiple classes missing like

TfsTeamProjectCollection,
GetService
Workspace
Most of the examples online seem to be centered around Git.
And the closest Ive got is to using
connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>
Though it does match for the Workspacesetup and get needs



Any help or pointers on this?

I can reproduce the issue using your scripts. The reason of the issue is that the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient package doesn't support Net Standard Client OM.

According to .NET client libraries,

Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient: Work with and manage version control, work items, and build, and other resources from your client application. This package doesn't support Net Standard Client OM. Only use this package when our REST APIs don't offer the functionality you need (for example, creating workspaces in TFVC)

And

This package includes our older SOAP object model, which we replaced by our newer REST object model. We're no longer investing in the older SOAP object model, and have no plans to create a NetStandard version of it.

Based on the current situation, it's suggested that you keep .Net 4.8.

Thanks and agreed... was actually looking for a confirmation that we hadnt missed some available approach.
So retaining the above code that works with 4.8
Also below is a working snippet with the new REST  client that works with .Net 8

var conn=new VssConnection(new Uri("https://org/tfs"), cred);
using(var client=conn.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>()){
 var items=client.GetItemsAsync("$/Project/Some/Component",VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result;
 foreach(var item in items){
  if(!item.IsFolder){
   // Fetch item content
   var fItem=client.GetItemAsync(path:item.Path,versionDescriptor:null,includeContent:true).Result;
   if(fItem.Content!=null){Console.WriteLine(fItem.Content);}}}}

can b tweaked 2 grow into a get workspace code...jus putting it out here

Hi @Cy Ra, thanks for your update and workaround.

posting code snip here as the same in reply to the comment was getting messed up
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;

namespace TfsWorkspaceExample;
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var cred = new VssBasicCredential("userid", "PAT");
        var conn = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://org/tfs"), cred);
        using (var client = conn.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>()) {
            var items = client.GetItemsAsync("$/Project/Some/Component", VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result;
            foreach (var item in items) {
                if (!item.IsFolder) {
                    var fItem = client.GetItemAsync(path: item.Path, versionDescriptor: null, includeContent: true).Result;
                    if (fItem.Content != null) {
                        Console.WriteLine(fItem.Content);
                    } } } } } }

package references added Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client
This is compatible with .Net 8 and can be further enhanced to build a custom  workspace get
